# How to 'build' a file from hexadecimal code?

Tags: hex

I'm a complete noob at this,

but say I have the following hexadecimal code, which I know is a png file by converting it to Ascii:

89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 c8 00 00 00 c8 01 03 00 00 00 97 96 3c
dd 00 00 00 06 50 4c 54 45 ff ff ff 00 00 00 55 c2 d3 7e 00 00 00 f8 49 44 41 54 58 85 ed 96 31
12 84 20 0c 45 e3 50 6c e9 11 3c 8a 47 83 a3 71 14 8f 60 69 e1 90 fd 01 66 15 d7 ad 4d 76 f8 45
44 9f 16 c1 9f 10 a2 ae 2e cb 9a 58 b4 cc 08 db 98 d7 ab 05 12 11 46 90 01 64 c1 fa 65 83 78 ··
f1 08 11 2f 20 da 22 39 1f 63 64 0e e4 4c 91 e2 9d 90 e4 72 e7 aa 07 49 ad c6 90 dc 8f 3a d5 48
aa d0 43 76 ba 95 4a 82 7c c8 95 ce 27 c2 7a b5 40 a2 27 b7 22 1f b8 86 17 df 76 3e b5 04 42 35 72 a4 fc cc b7 de d1 4b 66 ·· ·· ab 0d bf 24 1d 1f 68 26 13 87 01 75 4a 75 ff 9b 0a d6 4b 3e 59 e5 3a bd 78 47 2d a9 3d 31 67 02 c7 27 77 ed 96 3a 49 a4 72 fe 48 3e e2 9d ef 93 e9 41 52 a6 8d ea 0d 9c 35 64 88 f8 7c e7 e9 90 01 22 73 88 f4 eb e1 3c fb 6b 26 54 a7 27 d9 7f 7f ee 7c 9a 49 a9 46 cc a3 c8 87 1b c7 2b 26 5d 5d ff a6 37 a5 e6 4e bb 4f 77 cf e7 00 00 00 00 49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82

the ..'s are unknown hex codes (at this stage).

And the ascii output:

�PNG

���
IHDR���È���È�����<Ý���PLTEÿÿÿ���UÂÓ… EãPlé<�G�£q�`iá�ýf×­MvøED�Á�¢®.Ë�… Ú"9cdäL�â��ärçªI­Æ�Ü�:ÕHªÐCvº�J�|È�Î'…
¿$h&�uJuÿ�
ÖK>Yå:½xG-©=1gÇ'wí�:I¤rþH>â�ï�éAR¦�ê
�5d�ø|çé�"s�ôëá<ûk&T§'Ùî|�I©FÌ£È�Ç…

How do I build an openable file (or at least partially openable) from this information? Also, is there a way to work backwards to determine what the missing hex codes must be? You might have to explain it slowly, I'm very much a beginner.

Any good resources on learning about ascii - hex - decimal - binary coding - filetypes and encryption would be very much appreciated also...

(This is related to the recent TF2 ARG).

Comment: well this is hex, I don't mind which language it gets interpreted in. I'm most familiar with java, but I've heard that's bad for most things...

Comment: hope some java lover is not here..else your questions fate is unknown..;)

Comment: well I personally don't mind it (insofar as the small tasks I've made it accomplish). I'm just referring to hearsay :p

Answer (score 0):

Simple C program

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  FILE *stream;

  int main( void )
    {    
       char s[3]={0};  

       if( fopen_s( &stream, "hex.txt", "r" ) != 0 )
          printf( "The file fscanf.out was not opened\n" );
       else
       {
          fseek( stream, 0L, SEEK_SET );
          while (fscanf(in_fd, "%s", s) != EOF) 
          {printf("%c",strtol((s,s+3,16));}   

          fclose( stream );
       }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add comments to explain your code? If I can just understand what;s going on, I might be better equipped to write something similar myself when the time arises...

Comment: running short of time(Office time),I will suggest you to copy the function name and do a google search. :)